# Pandas `transform(set)` raising exception

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, set, transform

I'm trying to transform by `set`, but I'm getting an exception. Transform works fine with "sum" and many other aggregate functions, but not with `set` or `list`.

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,1,], "b":[1,1,2]})
>>> df
   a  b
0  1  1
1  2  1
2  1  2
>>> df.groupby("a").b.transform(set)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/avloss/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py", line 1032, in transform
    s = klass(res, indexer)
  File "/Users/avloss/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 282, in __init__
    "{0!r} type is unordered" "".format(data.__class__.__name__)
TypeError: 'set' type is unordered
```

What I was expecting was:

```py
   a      b   
0  1  {1, 2}
1  2     {1}
2  1  {1, 2}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have `unique`, notice `unique` will even keep the original order of your input

```
df.groupby('a').b.transform('unique')
0    [1, 2]
1       [1]
2    [1, 2]
Name: b, dtype: object
```

Update if above not work
, try below

```
df.groupby('a').b.transform(lambda x : [set(x)]*len(x))
0    {1, 2}
1       {1}
2    {1, 2}
Name: b, dtype: object
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to work anymore, at least as of pandas 1.0.1: 
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/31849

Comment: @geo909 some other work around `df.groupby('a').b.transform(lambda x : [set(x)]*len(x))
0    {1, 2}
1       {1}
2    {1, 2}
Name: b, dtype: object
`

Answer (score 5):

Easiest way I can think of is `aggregate` as `set` and map it back

```
df['new_col'] = df['a'].map(df.groupby('a')['b'].agg(set))
print(df)
```

---

```
   a  b new_col
0  1  1  {1, 2}
1  2  1     {1}
2  1  2  {1, 2}
```